# Install Google Calendar on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, calendar, google

I've just replaced Ubuntu 18.04 with 22.04. On the old OS I had a desktop shortcut to my Google Calendar. Is there a way to have the same thing on Ubuntu 22.04?

Comment: Tried "Chromium/Chrome/Edge" Webpage App (might be called different) ?

Comment: @Marco  In the Chrome Web Store I found only extensions to be used within the browser. I want to be able to open the calendar without going anywhere else first.

Comment: Not as an extension. In Chrome it is the "Create Shortcut" menu entry. In Edge it is called "Install this site as an app".

Comment: @Marco Yes, that worked. I installed Chromium from Ubuntu Software. I signed in to my Gmail account and opened the calendar. Then: 3 dots in upper right > More Tools > Create Shortcut > Open as Window > Create. Right-click on desktop icon > Allow launching. I now have Google Calendar on my 22.04 desktop. Thank you.